# Change the text on changing image in android

Tags: android, android-view

I have a horizontal scroll view with array list of images and the text field below the scroll view,how could i change the text on changing image in horizontal scrollview.

```
For Example: The image will show Mountain the text will also texted with mountain
```

**Here The image will only scroll, the text view will remain fix, it will change the name with images only**

I have used the code below for scrolling image ,it is working fine, images are changing but the textview didn't change !!

could anybody help me !!  @Thanks in advance

```
 public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {


            vi=convertView;


            if(convertView==null){
                vi = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.screen, null);

               position_pin = position;

              Holder.images=(ImageView) vi.findViewById(R.id.image);
              Holder.textview=(TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.name);



             Holder.images.setImageResource(imageIds[position]);
           Holder.text.setText(name);

             vi.setTag(Holder);   

            }

                        return vi;
            }




If you have any better option or code then help me.
```

[image]

Comment: Where are you getting `name` from?

Comment: @codeMagic name is string from webservice

Comment: @codeMagic is there any possibility to make like that!!

Comment: Sure but `name` has to change. I would put them in an `ArrayList` that corresponds with your Image `Array`. Unless I don't understand what you have

Comment: @codeMagic thanks fine..how could the text array relate with the images

Answer (score 0):

I guess problem is in about your way to get correspond name.But you have an option(however it is strange!):

You can merge each image and it's description to another image and only show the result.If you want to do this,you can use your `R.layout.screen` or directly use a canvas and add your image and desired description to it.

Comment: @thanks for your response ,suppose i have the image with description then how could i relate with each other!!

Answer (score 0):

```
Arraylist<String> nameList = new ArrayList<String>();
// add your names the same way you add your images to your images array
...
name = nameList.get(position);
textView.setText(name);
```

I would think something like that should work

It looks like you are using a `ViewHolder` so you should add to your `if` statement

```
else
        {
            Holder = (ViewHolder) vi.getTag();
        }
```

To reuse your `Views`

Comment: Ok, let me know how it works out. I've done things like this before and it has worked for me.

Comment: It has in the past. It should for you if you do something similar to how you do your `imageIds` `imageIds[position]`

Comment: but in view item i have choosed different layout and for listview different layout

Comment: I don't know what you are saying but why can't you do it like you have with the image ids? You just get the position as you do with the id

Comment: using that can i get the position respect to images

Comment: Yes, have you tried it yet. If you are using the same type of `Array` for your images and you use the same `position` why wouldn't it?

Comment: But How it will correspond to the image?

Comment: i have tried every possibilities,what ever you update,but still the first value of the string is getting

Answer (score 0):

Your code suggests that you set the text only when the convertView is null. Generally adapter views are re-cycled so the update should happen even when a new view isn't formed.

Comment: Can you post your layout xml ? that should help identify the issue. also in your code you find  Holder.textview but set text to Holder.text